# SharePoint 2013 - import into a Promoted Links list

Tags: 2013, import, promoted-links

I have a site owner with a list of over 100 links to bring into a Promoted Links list. Is there a simple way to do this? The combined URL and description for the background image and the link itself are giving us trouble.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to export the list with links to Excel, and reformat it + add links to your description and background image for each field, and then use quick edit in a promoted links list to copy paste the content from the Excel directly to the list in SharePoint.

The limit is 100 for each copy paste. If you are below 200 links, it should be quick.

If you are unsure how to format the excel to match the promoted links column, just create one tile in the promoted links list and then export it to excel. This should give you the idea what information you need to provide to be able to bulk-upload the tiles.